# Assigning probabilities in a minimization problem

Tags: probability, optimization

I have several chromosomes, each of them has a fitness which shows the value of that chromosome. For example, if my problem is a maximization problem, the chromosome with the highest fitness is the best one. In this case, we calculate the probability of chromosome $i$ this way:

$p_i = f_i / \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^n f_k$

So if my fitness values are $f_1$ = $2$, $f_2 = 5$ and $f_3 = 3$, their probabilities would be $p_i = 2/10$, $p_2 = 5/10$ and $p_3 = 3/10$.

So my question is about when I have a minimization problem. In this case the chromosome with the lowest fitness is the most valuable one and it should take the highest probability. How can I assign probabilities to values in a minimization problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't have the probabilities be $1-p_i$ and maximize that?

Comment: @79037662 I'm not sure if I understand what you mean completely. Can you explain using an example for minimization (my example for example)?

Comment: In your example, define $p_1=8/10, p_2=5/10, p_3=7/10$. The probabilities don't add to 1, but if you maximize this problem you'll find the min of your original problem. If you need them to add to 1, maybe divide by $n-1$.

Comment: What exactly is the objective function here, that is, what are you trying to minimize/maximize?

Comment: @79037662 In my minimization problem, I want the chromosome with lower fitness value, get higher probabilities. These probabilities will later be used in selection. I mean the chromosomes with higher probabilities will have a better chance to be selected.

Comment: In that case you can do what I suggested, which is take $1-p_i$, divide by $n-1$ and use those probabilities.

Comment: @79037662 So in my example, $n-1$ is equal to 2 and the probabilities would be $p_1 = 8/20$, $p_2 = 5/20$ and $p_3 = 7/20$. right? If so, why do we use $n-1$ not $n$?

Comment: Do you need the probabilities to add up to $1$? If so, you need to divide the values by $n-1$. If not, you don't need to divide at all.

Comment: The reason you divide by $n-1$ is because $\sum_{k=1}^n(1-p_k)=n-\sum_{k=1}^np_k=n-1$.

Comment: @79037662 Yes they should be equal to 1. So here is the formula, $p_i$ = ((sum of all fitness values) - $f_i$) / (sum of all fitness values)*$(n-1)$ for minimization right?

Comment: Not quite, it would be $p_i=(1-(f_i/\sum_{k=1}^nf_k))/(n-1)$. EDIT: If this is actually equivalent to what you wrote, then yes.